# How to get contact name from number using like in selection in android

Tags: android

Here is the code which iam using

```
    private String getContactNameFromNumber(String number) {
        // define the columns I want the query to return
        String[] projection = new String[] {
                Contacts.Phones.DISPLAY_NAME,
                Contacts.Phones.NUMBER };

        // encode the phone number and build the filter URI
        Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Contacts.Phones.CONTENT_FILTER_URL, Uri.encode(number));

        // query time
        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(contactUri, projection, null,
                null, null);

        // if the query returns 1 or more results
        // return the first result
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            String name = c.getString(c
                    .getColumnIndex(Contacts.Phones.DISPLAY_NAME));
            return name;
        }

        // return the original number if no match was found
        return number;
    }
```

but this code returns only number exactly equal to contact number.
i want to use like statement so that even last 7 numbers matches i should be able to get the name..
how to write that..?

Answer (score 7):

Retrieving Name from Phones Contacts using Phone Number

```
private String getContactNameFromNumber(String number) { 
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(number));


    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME},null,null,null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
    }   


    return name;
    //proceed as you need 

}
```

Comment: please don't shout (aka: all upper-case letters) and fix your code formatting :-)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
private String getContactNameFromNumber(String number) {
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

    String [] projection = new String []{
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME
    };
    String selection = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + " LIKE ? ";;
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{"%"+number+ "%"};

    Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
        projection,
        selection,
        selectionArgs,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");

    //proceed as you need
    ...
}
```