# Get current contacts from messaging app

Tags: android

I want to be able to pull the contact info, (name and number) of the contacts that have text message (sms) conversations currently stored in the default text messaging application on the device. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Iterate through the conversations, pull the names, then find their contact?

Comment: Yes this is exactly what i want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might want query the below uri to get all the addresses which are addressed in sms and mms

```
content://mms-sms/conversations
```

you need to get `address` column

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver(); 
    final String[] projection = new String[]{"*"}; 
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations/"); 
    Cursor query = contentResolver.query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    String phone = "";
    while(query.moveToNext()){
    phone = query.getString(query.getColumnIndex("address"));
    Log.d("test",phone);
    }
```

Edit:
You can check the below function copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6994107/1109425). Pass the number picked from above address column to this function

```
private String getContactNameFromNumber(String number) {
    // define the columns I want the query to return
    String[] projection = new String[] {
            Contacts.Phones.DISPLAY_NAME,
            Contacts.Phones.NUMBER };

    // encode the phone number and build the filter URI
    Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Contacts.Phones.CONTENT_FILTER_URL, Uri.encode(number));

    // query time
    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(contactUri, projection, null,
            null, null);

    // if the query returns 1 or more results
    // return the first result
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        String name = c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndex(Contacts.Phones.DISPLAY_NAME));
        c.close();
        return name;
    }
    c.close();
    // return the original number if no match was found
    return number;
}
```

You will have to edit this to match your query since calling this for each and every number will be slow.

Comment: Do you know of an example of how i could do that?

Comment: Thanks, but where would i get the numbers for the contacts that have sms or mms messages stored on the phone?

Comment: the "//" in `content://` comments out my code... sorry to be a pain

Comment: oops. I didnt see that. changed again :)

Comment: Thank you I tried it and it works, quick question though it pulled like 25 numbers, it looks like its pulling the numbers of anyone ive every texted, not just those who i have saved messages from, is this what is supposed to happen?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15433/discussion-between-nandeesh-and-peter)